# ImportError: cannot import name 'find_stack_level' from 'pandas.util._exceptions'

Tags: python, pandas, yolov5

When I tried to run the `YOLOv5` `train.py`, I don't know what was wrong with it. `pandas` is installed.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jasmine/Desktop/fyp/yolov5/yolov5/utils/general.py", line 26, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "/home/jasmine/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from pandas.core.api import (
  File "/home/jasmine/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/api.py", line 14, in <module>
    from pandas.core.algorithms import factorize, unique, value_counts
  File "/home/jasmine/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/algorithms.py", line 58, in <module>
    from pandas.core.indexers import validate_indices
  File "/home/jasmine/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexers/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pandas.core.indexers.utils import (
  File "/home/jasmine/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexers/utils.py", line 18, in <module>
    from pandas.util._exceptions import find_stack_level
ImportError: cannot import name 'find_stack_level' from 'pandas.util._exceptions' (/home/jasmine/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/util/_exceptions.py)
```

Comment: which version of pandas you have installed?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a similar problem with pandas version `1.4.2`.
Try using a different pandas version.
version `1.3` worked for me.

Comment: same with me, I was having problem running code with groupby and cumcount()

Answer (score 1):

I had this when upgrading from pandas `1.3.x` to `1.4.2`. In my case deleting my conda env and recreating fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with pandas version `1.2.4`. I found out that my pip version was an older one. So, I upgraded pip using

> C:\Anaconda\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip

which installed pandas version `1.3.2` and solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem too. I had `pandas-1.5.2` on my production server. Simply ran `pip3 install pandas==1.3.2` and it solved my issue.